# How can I solve this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation

$x^2y'' + a\,x\,y' + b\,y = 0 \text{ where } y = y(x) \text{ and } a,b \in R$

Using the change of variable $u = \ln(x)$, how can I transform the differential equation in the form of?

$Z'' + \alpha Z'+ \beta Z = 0 \text{ where } Z = Z(u)$

And what are the values ​​of $\alpha \text{ and }\beta$ as a function of a and b?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know the chain rule?

Comment: @in_wolfram_we_trust Yep, but I don't know how to use de chain rule to solve this.

Comment: It is so called an Euler Equation. For details you may check http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m23s06/public_html/handouts/euler_eqns.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $u=\ln{x}$ we get:
$$y'_x=y'_uu'_x=y'_u\frac{1}{x},$$
$$y''_{xx}=(y'_x)'_x=y'_u(-\frac{1}{x^2})+y''_{uu}\frac{1}{x^2}.$$
The differential equation becomes
$y''-y'+ay'+by=0$, where $y=y(u)$. Values $\alpha$, $\beta$ are
$$\alpha=a-1$$ and 
$$\beta=b.$$
Finally, the roots of characteristic equation $\lambda^2+(a-1)\lambda+b=0$ are
$$\lambda_1=\frac{1-a+\sqrt{(a-1)^2-4b}}{2},$$
$$\lambda_2=\frac{1-a-\sqrt{(a-1)^2-4b}}{2},$$
so solution to the differential equation is
$$y(u)=C_1 e^{\lambda_1 u}+C_2 e^{\lambda_2 u},$$
or 
$$y(x)=C_1 x^{\frac{1-a+\sqrt{(a-1)^2-4b}}{2}}+C_2 x^{\frac{1-a-\sqrt{(a-1)^2-4b}}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $u = \ln x$.

Then by chain rule we have
$$ \begin{array}{lll} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} & = & \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\\ & = & \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{1}{x}.\end{array} $$

Comment: Good hint. Thank you!